# How can I get precise location with google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to show the user's current location on map. Using the HTML5 geolocation it asks the user for permission, which I find annoying and I found I could bypass this by using directly the google maps api.

The problem is that with either solution the accuracy can be well off (300km off).

## HTML5 solution

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

This is the example that google provides and it is well off. Also the accuracy changes from browser to browser.

## Google maps api solution

This is the code I've reached to.

```
function calculateZoomLevel(accuracy) {
    var equatorLength = 40075004; // in meters
    var mapWidth = 480; // in pixels
    var metersPerPixel = equatorLength / 4096;
    var zoomLevel = 1;
    while ((metersPerPixel * mapWidth) > accuracy) {
        metersPerPixel /= 2;
        zoomLevel++;
    }
    return Math.min(zoomLevel, 17);
}
function initMap() {
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(37.990832, 23.70332), accuracy = 0;
    $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_API_KEY').done(function(e) {
        coords = new google.maps.LatLng(e.location.lat, e.location.lng);
        accuracy = e.accuracy;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: calculateZoomLevel(accuracy),
            center: coords,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        });
        new google.maps.Circle({
            center: coords,
            radius: accuracy,
            map: map,
            fillColor: '#ff0000',
            fillOpacity: .5,
            strokeColor: '#ff0000',
            strokeOpacity: .5
        });
    }).fail(function(e) {
        console.log('fail ajax post geolocation', e);
    });
}
```

The thing is, I know the precision can be quite good (10-30 meters), since at the same time and on the same browser I see myself somewhere totally off on google's example, I see myself at my spot in the normal google maps page.

Comment: accuracy of browsers geolocation is determined by many factors. Allowing a site to use that information is also up to the users discretion. The non-browser method probably uses the users IP address, which you've already found out is (thankfully) not very accurate

Comment: The browser does not have any way of determining location, it is dependent on the host system. The location can be provided by various means, such as GPS, mobile phone tower trilateration or IP detection. If you bypass the user's permission, then it will likely fallback to IP detection, which, for me, is up to 1,000km out.

Comment: The google example asks for permission and has the same accuracy as the one with google api. Pretty sure that's because the browser solution is based on the google api too. Either way google maps official page does not ask for permissions and it's quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

So if you don't want to capture and calculate most possible position at the cost of a lot of requests or you don't want to make your own script to connect to this api which would be a challenge...
Create a looping threshold. Recall your function if it is not a reasonable accuracy. Meaning:

```
   coords = new google.maps.LatLng(e.location.lat, e.location.lng);
   accuracy = e.accuracy;
var c = 0;
if (c<20){
     If (accuracy <100){
         .. do your stuff..
     }else{
         initMap();
         c++;
     }
}else{
     ...failed....
}
```

So word to the wise... This will increase your requests in obvious ways. You have been warned..... Unless google allows unlimited requests for free when you read this.